# To have no LaTeX margins for pictures

Tags: image, latex

I have many types of diagrams in my paper.
I use at the moment horizontal pages to make pictures readable.

I would like to know how you can remove `LaTeX` margins from pages where there are pictures.

How can you have no margins for pictures in `LaTeX`?

Comment: To those voting to close. Not my answer "diddle the variable" when you are re-setting variable values, you are programming. The fact that he can drap in a class file doesn't change that unless you think that dragging in PODs makes perl not programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either [diddle the various variables directly](http://web.image.ufl.edu/help/latex/margins.shtml) or use the [`geometry` package](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=geometry).

LaTeX uses a lot of variable to describe the page, so setting them directly is a hassle, I really reccomend using `geometry`.

And remember there is a silent 1 inch margin. Moreover how close to the edge of the page you can actually print is dependent on you printer. Most won't actually let you get to the edge on any side.

Comment: The geometry package finally solves the problem. - Thank you!

Comment: geometry only works for the whole document, right?

Comment: @Will: Not positive, but I think so. This is the nth question related to another of Masi's ambitious projects. I think that he really only want to have a bunch of full page pictures.

Comment: @Will @dmckee The `geometry` package v5 claims that you can do `\newgeometry{...} blah blah blah blah \restoregeometry` to make changes that apply to a proper subset of the document, but I can't get that feature to work.

Comment: @LaoTzu Yes, you're correct. Good to see the new feature, since it is a common question. I haven't used it myself though.

Comment: \newgeometry{margin=0in} works for me

Comment: `\geometry{margin=0mm}\newpage` works for me, too. `\layout` doesn't recognize it, though.

Answer (score 5):

The [changepage](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/misc/changepage.sty) package can be used to locally change the size of the area that content is put in. Documentation within the `.sty` file until I get around to writing a real manual.

Answer (score 4):

I did this exact thing before. Here's the code:

```
\newenvironment{changemargin}{%
 \begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\topsep}{-1in}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{-1.5in}%
   \setlength{\rightmargin}{-1.5in}%
   \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
   \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
   \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
 }%
\centering%
\item[]%
}{\end{list}}
```

On the page in question, I also used `\clearpage`, `\pagestyle{empty}` and `enlargethispage{...}`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm doing `\newenvironment{marg}{ \begin{figure} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.8in} \includegraphics{mypic} \end{figure} }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the width of the figure to be bigger than \textwidth.

I think includegraphics is the non-clipping version, (as opposed to includegraphics*)

I assume this would work as long as the vertical size would fit on the page.

Otherwise I'd look on CTAN for packages which allow you to change the margins on the fly.

Comment: Though it will throw overfull hbox warning all over the place.